# Preventing foreach loop from multiple execution - PHP

Tags: php, header

**Code explanation:** The given provided code is about ordering the items in a ecommerce website and trigger the php mailer to send cart items on a specific email address via email.

Once their is an item inside the `$_SESSION["shopping_cart"]` then it first condition check whether `$_SESSION["shopping_cart"]` is empty or not.

if its not empty then else part will be executed.

**NOTE: part_1.php, part_2.php , part_2.php are HTML email templates.**

**Inside the else part:** I am using `foreach` loop and insert the values inside the DB one by one. which is done successfully also emails are arriving as well with all items on it.

**Mail example:**
[image: here]

**Problem:**

```
if($run==true){
    header('location:../checkout.php?er=false');
    unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);  
     $run=false;
  }
```

Now I want to `unset` the `$_SESSION["shopping_cart"]` and redirect the user to **checkout.php** page once the loop finish rendering all the items into the db and email send successfully.
But instead I am getting this error everytime: `No orders have been placed - We can only process your order with at least 1 order.`

I already check `$_SESSION["shopping_cart"]`  using `var_dump` and always has a value inside of it.
what I assume the problem is in foreach loop which run multiple times and once `unset` the session it execute multiple times and page check the  `if(empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])|| $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] =='')` again.

```
  $run = true; 
  $shown=0;
  $order_prefer = 1;        
  if(empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])|| $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] =='')
    {   
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                  No orders have been placed - We can only process your order with at least 1 order.
        </div>';
    }
    else
    {
        //include email template parts
        include "src/order_send/part_1.php";
        include "src/order_send/part_2.php";
                            
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $number => $val)
        {
         // prepare and bind
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO purchase(guest_code,productid,quantity,date_purchase,time_purchase) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("siiss",$_COOKIE['CODE'],$val['product_id'],$val['product_quantity'],$current_date,$current_time); 
            $stmt->store_result();  

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
              $st = $conn->prepare("SELECT productid, productname FROM product WHERE productid= ?");
              $st->bind_param("i",$val['product_id']); 
              $st->bind_result($productid,$productname);
              $st->store_result();
              $st->execute();
              while ($st->fetch())
               { 
                 $json=array('pid'=>$productid,'pname'=>$productname);
                                                                                        
                $body .='<tr>
                           <td><center><span class="badge  text-center" style="background: #65cc0b;">'.$order_prefer.'</span></center></td>
                           <td>'.$json['pid'].'</td>
                           <td>'.$json['pname'].'</td>
                           <td>'.$val['product_quantity'].'</td>
                                                                                                    
                        </tr>';

                       $order_prefer++;     
                }

            $st->close();
            $stmt->close(); 

            }else
            {
                if($shown==0) //show msg only once
                 {
                    echo 'ERROR: while placing your order. Please contact restaurant owner';
                    header('location:../checkout.php?er=true');
                    $shown = 1;
                                                                                    
                  }

                $st->close();
                $stmt->close(); 
                                                                            }
                   if($run==true){
                     header('location:../checkout.php?er=false');
                     unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']); 
                     $run=false;
                    }
                                                        
                }


        //include email template parts
            include "src/order_send/part_3.php";
                                     
                $status_query ="SELECT status from mailing";
                $sq=$conn->query($status_query);
                $main_result =$sq->fetch_array();
                if(isset($main_result['status']) && $main_result['status']=='ON') 
                {
                        $mails->msgHTML($body);
                        $mails->Subject = 'Incoming order';
                        $mails->send(); //echo 'error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                                                  
                }
           }
```

Comment: You might want to wrap it in try, catch and throw exception to exit the desired block of code its the only way to exit nested for, foreach, while, do while loops

Comment: where and which part should be in try and catch can you specify?

Comment: The foreach you'd like to exit

Comment: I am not facing any error in try catch block.. the foreach loop run multiple time...example: if there is 2 items in the  cart the the foreach loop run 2 times to renter the items. But what I want is if.. after rendering the all loops I want to redirect and unset the session.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understood when you redirect you also set ?er=false and the same php file will handle the redirect also. I think the problem is that you dont handle the case when you get the GET param 'er'

Coulkd you maybe try:

```
if((empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]) || $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] =='') && @$_GET['er'] !== 'false')
```

Comment: Nops, thats doesn't what you meant about er here...

Comment: the thing is... when you do not unset the session then foreach loop will goes to infinite loop.

Comment: Try not to use `@` operator to suppress warnings and notices, especially in production. You should instead check for the index to be exist, or use `??` operator instead. See [the Warning in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).